# Webpack blob names for CSS modules

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

I've set up webpack 2 with CSS modules, and it works. However, when I debug the CSS via the browser debugger, all the paths are like this:
"blob:http://localhost:3000/2b5f9ab7-7972-4c8a-bdbd-96cd9e74b6f9"

This makes it impossible for me to identify the CSS modules. Is there some way I can get webpack to write out the module name instead?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you even though I don't think is the optimal solution.
Try with [manifest revision plugin](https://github.com/nickjj/manifest-revision-webpack-plugin), what it does is to generate a **manifest.json** file, where there are all the references your project is using. 
Add the plugin to webpack.config

```
new manifest('manifest.json', {
        rootAssetPath: '/public/css',
        ignorePaths: []
      })
```

Then in the manifest.json you will find the *equivalences*, this way you can know what file is using your project.

```
{
  "assets":
  {"./bootstrap.min.css":"e02a995e6786d8aa55ee397094f88d16.css"}
}
```